# About adding a snippet for python in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

How to write a snippet for 'main' function in vs code? It's not allowing to put double "" in between the body. Here is what I have written:

```
"Print to console": {
        "prefix": "mai",
        "body": [
            "if __name__ == __main__:"
            
        ],
        "description": "This throws main"
```

And I want this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   pass
```

How to make this snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste into https://snippet-generator.app/  that formats it into the necessary json.  You copy that (there’s a button) and then you just paste it into your snippet file.

For who need to know I'd guess you just have to do the right escape `"foo" : "\"bar\""` (I think).  Then again, Python is OK with single quotes and json doesn't care about about those so `"foo" : "'bar'"` would also bear looking into.  Snippet generator does not round trip, so I do typically have to edit existing snippets with the correct escape/quotes strategy, but it's easier to get 95% of the thing right and then do tweaks than write embedded Python in json all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one.

```py
"Print to console": {
        "prefix": "mai",
        "body": [
            "if __name__ == '__main__':",
            "\tpass"
        ],
        "description": "Whatever you want to write."
    }
```